# Installing PhpMyAdmin in conjunction with Nginx

Tags: raspbian, web-server, mysql

I've got MySQL and Nginx installed on my raspberry pi, but I can't seem to find a guide that explains how I would install phpmyadmin with nginx on my raspberry pi, and be able to access it through nginx too. Would someone mind explaining the process here?

Comment: Do you intend to install from sources or through your distro's packages? If the latter, which one do you use? Have you seen this tutorial for example?

http://www.howtoforge.com/running-phpmyadmin-on-nginx-lemp-on-debian-squeeze-ubuntu-11.04

Comment: I tried following that, but when I attempt to connect to phpnyadmin I get "The page you are looking for is temporarily unavailable. Please try again later".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommendation is to simply download the latest version of PMA from phpmyadmin.net.  Create a virtual host in NginX for your PHPMyAdmin installation, and extract the contents of the file you downloaded to the document root.